# Pick multiple items in JMeter CSV Data Set?

Tags: jmeter

I have a JMeter test that uses a CSV Data Set Config to provide a list of products for each simulated user to purchase.

The test is simple:

- login
- pick product to add to cart
- checkout
- logout.

This has worked well and now I want to simulate a user purchasing N products. I first tried duplicating the controllers that pick a product and also tried putting those in a loop controller, but in both cases they just add the same product to the cart repeatedly.

What I want is for each user to pick multiple items from the CSV file. I tried modifying settings for the CSV Data Set Config, but I get the same results no matter what I set it to. Am I missing something or is this expected behavior?

How do I get a thread to pick different items from the CSV file?
Is my only choice to provide multiple CSV files and use multiple CSV Data Set Configs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your option is to use [__StringFromFile function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) inside a [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller)

You could then use some Beanshell to process the line and split items.

Comment: Cool. I missed that one while looking for a solution, I'll give it a try right now, thanks! It looks like it only gets a single item per line, and my CSV file pulls five items per line. I'll have to think about how to work around that.

Comment: I managed to find a way to use a single item without parsing it, and the simpler the better! That worked well, I just created a file with a product id on each line and in the HTTP Request's path I used: `/cart/add/product/${__StringFromFile(products_extras.csv,extraProdId,,)}` which does the right thing.